# Perl -> How return value of qx(perl file)

Tags: perl, return-value, qx

I need to know how is possible return values of Perl file from other Perl file.

In my first file i call to the second file with sentence similar to:

```
$variable = qx( perl file2.pl --param1 $p1 --param2 $p2);
```

I have tried with exit and return to get this data but is not possible.

Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by a process's "return value"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `file2.pl`, you must [print](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html) something to STDOUT.  For example:

```
print "abc\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

Processes are no subroutines.

Communication between processes (“IPC”) is mostly done via normal file handles. Such file handles can specifically be

- STDIN and STDOUT,
- pipes that are set up by the parent process, these are then shared by the child,
- sockets

Every process also has an *exit code*. This code is zero for success, and non-zero to indicate a failure. The code can be any integer in the range 0–255. The exit code can be set via the `exit` function, e.g. `exit(1)`, and is also set by `die`.

Using STDIN and STDOUT is the normal mode of operation for command line programs that follow the [*Unix philosophy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy). This allows them to be chained with pipes to more complex programs, e.g.

```
cat a b c | grep foo | sort >out
```

Such a tool can be implemented in Perl by reading from the ARGV or STDIN file handle, and printing to STDOUT:

```
while (<>) {
  # do something with $_
  print $output;
}
```

Another program can then feed data to that script, and read it from the STDOUT. We can use `open` to treat the output as a regular file handle:

```
use autodie;
open my $tool, "-|", "perl", "somescript.pl", "input-data"; # notice -| open mode
while (<$tool>) {
  ...
}
close $tool;
```

When you want all the output in one variable (scalar or array), you can use `qx` as a shortcut: `my $tool_output = qx/perl somescript.pl input-data/`, but this has two disadvantages: One, a shell process is executed to parse the command (shell escaping problems, inefficiency). Two, the output is available only when the command has finished. Using `open` on the other hand allows you to do parallel computations.

Answer (score 1):

print is the solution.

Sorry for my idiot question!

Comment: It should be a comment and not an answer

Answer (score 0):

#

```
 $variable = system( perl file2.pl --param1 $p1 --param2 $p2);
 #$variable has return value of perl file2.pl ...
```